# how do you create filters on time series data in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

there is a file that has entries like this:

> 2016-01-22 10:01:44.043, cash.read, 93.67088
>
> 2016-01-22 10:01:44.043, cahhe.size, 79

```
<timestamp>   <metric> <value>
```

There are 1000's of metrics. Can somebody guide me through creating filter to create entries in logstash to push it to elasticsearch?

Comment: Have you met the grok debugger or read any information on learning to use grok?  http://svops.com/blog/introduction-to-logstash-grok-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grok` and `kv` filters to achive that.
The filter will be something like:

```
filter {
   grok {
        match => {
        message => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:metrics}"
        }
        }

  date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
    }


  kv {
        source => "metrics"
        value_split => ","
        trim => " "
        remove_field => [ "metrics", "message" ]
    }

}
```